# SQL Server - Declaring a dynamic amount of variables (ANOVA)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, anova

I'm trying to create an [ANOVA F-Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test#One-way_ANOVA_example) stored procedure in SQL Server (purely from a conceptual standpoint - Is it even possible?)

The thing I am having the most difficulty with is declaring an unspecified amount of variables. I want my user to be able to specify an undetermined amount of columns to perform the test on. Here is how my proc is set up so far:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ANOVA
@ColumnList nvarchar(MAX),
@table nvarchar(MAX),
@null varchar(5) = 'eq'
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #columns (col varchar(250))
    INSERT INTO #columns SELECT ItemValue FROM dbo.SplitList(@ColumnList, ',')
    --SplitList is a table-valued function that splits a comma delimited list into a table.
    DECLARE @NumVars int, @i int = 0, @TotMean float, @SQL nvarchar(MAX)
    SELECT @NumVars = COUNT(*) FROM #columns
END
```

This is just the skeleton I have so far. In my mind, I have two ways to approach this.

Use Dynamic SQL to declare variables and do the whole ANOVA procedure in one Dynamic SQL statement:

```
SELECT @SQL =
'WHILE ' +  CAST(@i AS varchar(50)) + ' < ' + CAST(@NumVars AS varchar) + ' 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @a' + CAST(@i AS varchar(5)) + ' varchar(50)
    DECLARE @a' + CAST(@i AS varchar(5)) + 'mean varchar(50)
    @i = @1 +1
END
/* ANOVA stuff goes here */'

EXEC (@SQL)
```

Or Use Dynamic SQL to declare variables into a table and work with them from there:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#vars') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #vars
CREATE TABLE #vars (vars varchar(250))
SELECT @SQL =
'WHILE ' +  CAST(@i AS varchar(50)) + ' < ' + CAST(@NumVars AS varchar) + ' 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #vars VALUES(''@a' + @i +''')
    @i = @i + 1
END
'

EXEC (@SQL)
--Declare means, do ANOVA stuff
```

I feel like getting this part done will be the hardest part of doing the ANOVA procedure. I have already done 1-sample and 2-sample t-tests and I felt like ANOVA was the next step.

I'm not looking for you guys to solve the whole problem for me, just to get started and maybe some suggestions of how to work with these variables

Comment: `Unspecified amount`: Why aren't you using a *table* for that?

Comment: Putting the unspecified number of variables into a table seems like the obvious solution to me.

Comment: Yes, but then how would you workwith the variables in the table if you don't know their names?

Answer (score 0):

How about creating an XML (with variable # of columns) and pass it to the Stored Procedure and Handle the XML inside the Stored Proc.

Comment: I haven't worked with XML that much.. But I can give it a try. I feel that there might be a simpler way to do it though.

Comment: How do u have your data in the front end or business  layer?
Do u need a help on the .Net side or in the Store Proc side or both?

Comment: I'm actually going to try using cursors for this. I have a little experience with them and I'll give it a shot. If that doesn't work I'll try to do XML.

Comment: Cursors are not recommended in most of the situations.
If u answer my questions above I can help you.

Comment: Yes, I know that Cursors are performance nightmares. But right now I'm worried about a conceptual level. I think I have it almost finished too.
But I plan on having my data stored in just a regular SQL database. I'd need help on the .Net side.

Comment: Also, right now, my cursor is only parsing through n = #columns specified by the user rows. I don't think parsing through 6 rows will take that long?